# Php array to list or table

Tags: php

I have this php:

```
print_r($lack->call('channels.archive'));
```

which returns:

```
Array ( [ok] => 1 [url] => https://thename.slack.com/ [team] => theTeam [user] => jason [team_id] => T1EDES561 [user_id] => U0DD74SB8 )
```

How can I get that array into a html list or table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short, one line code solution:

```
echo "<ul><li>" . implode('</li><li>', $lack->call('channels.archive')) . "</li></ul>";
```

[An example here.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vu5nJj)

Comment: I like this! Why didn't I think of it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print a simple table of all the keys and values, you can do this:

```
<?php
    echo "<table>";

    // header row ... not necessary
    echo "<tr><th>Key></th><th>Value</th></tr>";

    // loop through the array
    foreach($lack->call('channels.archive') as $key => $val) {

        // prints out header as a `<th>` and value as a `<td>
        echo "<tr><th>$key</th><td>$val</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```